# how to setup nginx reverse proxy for nodejs

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy

I tried a lot for this, but not working.
help me any one please..

node is at port 3000 and nginx is at 8080 in localhost

this is node index

```
var express=require('express'),app=express(),cors =require('cors');
app.use(cors({origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'}));
app.get('/home', (req, res) => {res.send("ok");});
app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1', function(){console.log('listening on port 3000..');});
```

this is nginx conf

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  127.0.0.1;

        location / {
            root   D:/www;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
}
```

If i use from frontend jQuery
http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/home
it's not working

if i use from frontend jQuery
http://127.0.0.1:3000/home
it's working

this is the error getting in IE,
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/home

Comment: can you add your nginx conf?

Comment: added, please check

Answer (score 1):

server name in nginx conf is not correct. Server names are defined using the server_name directive and determine which server block is used for a given request. They may be defined using exact names, wildcard names, or regular expressions. Replace it with localhost.
For more info read [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

Comment: tried with localhost, localhost:8080, 0.0.0.0:8080, 0.0.0.0  but not worked

Comment: maybe its problem of Nginx cutting HOST header before passing to upstream and request catches by default server. Puting this `proxy_set_header Host $host;` before proxy_pass might help

Comment: tried, not working. Please Give me working nginx conf file for nodejs, Thanks.

Comment: this is a full example on nginx site [nginx conf](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/)